# How to get a user input to reference the dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having a slight bit of trouble trying in my Python assignment. In the assignment, I am required to create a credit program for a grocery store. It is pretty easy stuff I'm just having trouble on my last part. So, we are required to take 3 user inputs to decide on the items that they would like to purchase. With these inputs, I need to take what the person has typed and turn it into a price. Also, I have been using `print('''''')`to skip lines, I have found several ways to remedy this but wasn't sure on the correct one.

Here is my assignment so far:

```
prices = {}  

aa = 5.  
bb = 4.  
cc = 10.  
dd = 3.  
ee = 5.  
ff = 4.  

prices[aa] = 'shrimp'
prices[bb] = 'groundbeef'
prices[cc] = 'tuna'
prices[dd] = 'sodapop'
prices[ee] = 'fruitplate'
prices[ff] = 'spicerack'

print("Hello and welcome to Lakeside Market:") #generic greeting

print('''''') #skip line

deposit = input("How much would you like to deposit into your account?")      #asks for a amount to deposit

print('''''') #skip line

deposit = int(deposit) #makes deposit variable an integer # turns deposit into an integer

bonus = 10 #creates $10 bonus if $20+ is taken from input

accountbalance = deposit + bonus # will be used when the user has entered a correct deposit amount

if deposit < 20: #basic if/else statement. If you put less than 20 it will tell you

    print("I'm sorry that doesn't meet the minimum requirement of $20")

    exit()

else: #if 20+ is entered

    print("Thank you, your funds have been deposited into your account.")

    print('''''') 

    print("Your balance is $",accountbalance) #balance is printed with first-time bonus of 10 added

    print('''''')

    print("We offer: shrimp, groundbeef, tuna, sodapop, fruitplate and spicerack") # here are the different items that can be input
    print("Please enter items as they appear above...") #item1 input

    print('''''')

    item1 = input("To begin, please enter an item name:") #item2 input

    item2 = input("Now, add a second item:")

    item3 = input("Finally, add your last item:") #item3 input
```

To complete the assignment, I need to turn the user inputs towards the end (`item1`, `item2`, `item3`) into the actual prices of the items from the `prices` dict. I will then add these items up, and subtract that amount from the `accountbalance` which will give me a new total on the account. I know this is very basic stuff, but I'm very new to Python and this is the first actual class I've had to take. Thanks for your time and replies in advance

Comment: I don't see any python dictionaries here. And your prices array is probably not going to behave as expected -- it's not a dictionary.

Comment: @rajah9, prices is a dict

Comment: Care to elaborate? I have seen multiple places on the site that says I can create a empty dictionary with the curly brackets. Can you explain WHY it will not behave?

Comment: Agreed, @PhillipMartin, but I think the OP needs to reverse keys and values, as your answer indicates. As written, the OP has shrimp and fruitplate both mapping to 5; similarly two values mapping to 4. The second would overwrite the first.

Comment: @rajah9. Thank you I understand now. I was having trouble deciding on which should be a key or value.

Comment: @rajah9, that's a good point. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to organize your items and prices differently for two reasons. The first, as @rajah9 pointed out, when using the prices as your keys you won't be able to map multiple items to the same price:

```
prices = {}
prices[1] = 'apple'
print prices[1]
''' output '''
'apple'

prices[1] = 'orange'
print prices[1]
''' output '''
'orange'
```

Second, you probably want easy access to prices from a given item. This is much more difficult if you use the prices as your keys. If you set the items as the keys and the prices as the values in your dictionary, then you can access the prices of each item by calling `prices[item]`.

```
prices = {}  

aa = 5.  
bb = 4.  
cc = 10.  
dd = 3.  
ee = 5.  
ff = 4.  

prices['shrimp'] = aa
prices['groundbeef'] = bb
prices['tuna'] = cc
prices['sodapop'] = dd
prices['fruitplate'] = ee
prices['spicerack'] = ff

# other stuff here ...

item1 = input("To begin, please enter an item name:") #item2 input

price1 = prices[item1]

item2 = input("Now, add a second item:")

price2 = prices[item2]

item3 = input("Finally, add your last item:") #item3 input

price3 = prices[item3]
```

Comment: This really helped, Phillip. Thank you for this. One question, since I am using predefined variables for my prices dictionary, would that not keep each item to a predetermined variable. Ex: shrimp and fruitplate are both 5.. Since the prices for these items is in its own variable (aa and ee), why would they get their values replaced?

Comment: Interesting question. `prices[aa]` is equivalent to `prices[5]`. A dictionary will store the value of the variable as the key and not the variable name itself.

Comment: Ahhhhh I see, so it will simply check that predetermined variable and use the integer provided. It doesn't really create a link from the dictionary key to its variable

Comment: Thank again. Really appreciated.